# How to keep trailing zero's in number to text conversion?

Tags: excel, vba, numbers

Ok, here is the case:

I have an Excel file in `.xlsx` format. One of the cells contains the value `132,6` and it's format is number. This means that Excel shows the number as `132,60`. Now because it represents a price (132 euro and 60 cents) I'd like to keep it in this format `132,60`.

[image]

Now I need to convert all cells to text format for purposes that aren't important in this question. Because the value is actually `132,6`, after the conversion this is the text value shown, instead of the `132,60`. But I'd like to maintain the trailing zero when converting it to text.

Is there any VBA implementation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this format should work

```
=TEXT(A2;"#'##0.00")
```

EDIT: In VBA
Below snippet will convert numbers in selection to text.

```
Sub aMacro()
  Dim SelRange As Range
  Set SelRange = Selection
  For Each c In SelRange.Cells
     c.Value = Format(c.Value, "###0.00")
  Next
End Sub
```